# Creating a fairytale for adults

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, fantasy, readers, fairytale

A short story fairytale that I've been thinking about writing and plotting out has recently given me pause.  It focuses on a witch and a princess who both cross faeries, but it isn't by any means for kids, and I don't want to make the mistake of simplifying it or dumbing it down, because it's very dark and complex.  How can I keep my fairytale mature and make it clear that the subject matter isn't for little kids?

Comment: Write it for adults.  Double check the marketing when it's published.  :-)

Comment: I would recommend watching a TV series called Happy Tree Friends. It makes it pretty clear that the subject isn't for little kids despite the art style.

Comment: Are you trying to write a story that uses familiar aspects of fairy-tales (kinds of characters, etc), but in a more adult style (greater depth and complexity of the conflict, less black-and-white morality, etc)? Or are you trying to write something that is *stylistically* a fairy tale (black-and-white morality, relatively simple conflict, etc) that is for adult consumption? That is, are you writing AU fairy-tale DarkFic, or fairy-tale stories for adults?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stories for adults, based on, or including elements of fairy tales, are quite common. For example, Neil Gaiman's *Snow, Glass, Apples* is a retelling of *Snow White*, with an evil vampire Snow White and a necrophiliac prince. "Not for children" doesn't begin to cover how dark and creepy that story is.

I would say, this trope is so common, **there's no reason why your readers would expect the story to be for children**, unless some weird decision by the publisher makes them think otherwise.